# How to make a loop for out-of-sample forecast

Tags: r, loops, forecasting

I am beginner to R and was hoping to have ideas for making a loop.

I would like to automate the following for each observation out of 726 observation making a 5 ahead out-of-sample forecast based on a rolling window of 1000 obsv, storing only the t+5 in the "pred" column and then reset the "VIX.Close" column to his original values.

```
require(highfrequency)
require(quantmod)
require(xts)

getSymbols("^VIX")

VIX_fcst_test <- VIX[, "VIX.Close"]
VIX_fcst_test$pred <- NA

VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[3000] <- predict(HARmodel(data = VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[2000:2999], periods = c(1, 5 , 22), type = "HAR", inputType = "RM"))
VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[3001] <- predict(HARmodel(data = VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[2001:3000], periods = c(1, 5 , 22), type = "HAR", inputType = "RM"))
VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[3002] <- predict(HARmodel(data = VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[2002:3001], periods = c(1, 5 , 22), type = "HAR", inputType = "RM"))
VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[3003] <- predict(HARmodel(data = VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[2003:3002], periods = c(1, 5 , 22), type = "HAR", inputType = "RM"))
VIX_fcst_test$pred[3004] <- predict(HARmodel(data = VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[2004:3003], periods = c(1, 5 , 22), type = "HAR", inputType = "RM"))

VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close <- VIX[, "VIX.Close"]
```

I tried this loop but I don't know how to make the last prediction into the "pred" column and reset the "VIX.Close" column.

```
for (i in 2000:2004) {
  HAREstimated <- HARmodel(data = VIX_fcst_test[i: (i+ 999), "VIX.Close"], periods = c(1, 5 , 22), type = "HAR", inputType = "RM")
  VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[i + 1000] <- predict(HAREstimated)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide the data so that we can have a minimum reproducible example? See here for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @HarrisonJones, just provided my MRE and updated my question. Thanks very much for having a look on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is the following:

- you first run the loop on each of the five sets of observations, with an IF statement for when you reach the final iteration which goes into the `pred` column instead of `VIX.close`
- you keep the reset of VIX.close outside of the for loop, otherwise it would have reset with each iteration

  ```
  for (i in 2000:2004) {
    if (i != 2004) {
      HAREstimated <- HARmodel(data = VIX_fcst_test[i:(i+999), "VIX.Close"], periods = c(1, 5 , 22), type = "HAR", inputType = "RM")
      VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close[i + 1000] <- predict(HAREstimated)
    } else {
      HAREstimated <- HARmodel(data = VIX_fcst_test[i:(i+999), "VIX.Close"], periods = c(1, 5 , 22), type = "HAR", inputType = "RM")
      VIX_fcst_test$pred[i + 1000] <- predict(HAREstimated)
    }
  }

  VIX_fcst_test$VIX.Close <- VIX[, "VIX.Close"]

  # final prediction
  VIX_fcst_test$pred[3004]
  ```

So really all you needed was an IF statement in your loop.